# Bypass duplicate when converting a lead

Tags: apex, duplicate-management

I'm trying to convert a lead to a contact, the lead has the same email than another contact, but I want to create a new contact. when I try to convert the lead, I got an error 'DUPLICATES_DETECTED : 
A contact with the same email address exists. Do you want to continue'.

And the lead is not converted.

It seems that the conversion is done with

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
//some parameters are set here
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
```

when I have to bypass duplicates when I'm trying to do an insert, I use something like that :

```
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;
Databsae.SaveResult sr2 = Database.insert(account, dml);
```

But in the case of a lead conversion I don't know if it is possible. 
I know there is a checkbox in the parameters of the lead in the admin part of salesforce, but this option does not do what I want, so I can't use that. I just want to bypass the duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have yet to find official documentation on this, but the `Database.convertLead` method actually accepts a second parameter, an instance of `Database.DMLOptions`. So I believe you should be able to do something like:

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
//some parameters are set here
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;
Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc, dml);
```

Source: the OfflineSymbolTable in IntelliJ/Illuminated Cloud

Comment: Note that if this does work, we should try to get the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm) updated...

Comment: Thank you a lot, I thought that the Database.DMLOptions would not work since it is not specified in the documentation, but it works very well ! And as you point it out, maybe the documentation should be updated...

Comment: I found a more useful page [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) and [requested to have it updated](https://twitter.com/WatsonRobertB/status/926150255875317760).

Comment: this is not working for me.  adding the dmloptions parameter causes lead conversion to skip the warning / not display the alert, but the lead conversion fails.  [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000204497&type=1) appears to indicate that all lead conversion will fail unless you turn off 'require validation for converted leads'.  still poking on this.

Comment: Thank you!! I wish I had found this solution sooner. It works perfectly to resolve the duplicates error on lead conversion and only requires a couple lines of code.